# How to use Volley to POST a string in the body and to save the binary response to a file

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection, android-volley, okhttp

I am currently using [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/), but I'd like to switch to [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html).
Maybe it is the late hour, but I can't seem to figure out how to send a POST request with just text in the body (in my app, the body is encrypted as a whole and then decrypted on the server side, and then split into params).
Also, my response should be a binary (not an image) that I'd like to save to a file.
I'm beginning to think that Volley isn't my best solution.
Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Realize you can use Volley and OkHttp. I'd even say It's recommended. Take a look at https://goo.gl/nl2DfN

Answer (score 1):

Use getParams to add body in POSt, like here

```
url = "http://google.com";
StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, 
new Response.Listener<String>() 
{
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        // response

    }
}, 
new Response.ErrorListener() 
{
     @Override
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         // error response

   }
}
) { 
@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() 
{  
        Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        params.put("param1", "aaa");  
        params.put("param2", "bbb");

        return params;  
}
};
queue.add(postRequest);
```

Volley is not designed for sending/receiving big data and multipart request. Best would be to have data in response base64 encoded.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't answer my question. There are many online references all showing your answer, but I want to send "lshdkjfgnslwn75986w709j58tpydnisuys0k9jt3y09jtc9yp83" in the body of the HTTP request and I don't know how to achieve using Volley.

Answer (score 1):

Volley offers a method [getBody()](http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/Request.html#getBody()) which you can use to put any data into the HTTP request body:

```
    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {

        byte[] body = new byte[0];
        try {
            body = mContent.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to gets bytes from content", e.fillInStackTrace());
        }
        return body;
    }
```